# CreateObject working in excel 2003 but not 2010

Tags: vba, excel

Essentially the code is just creating a text file in a directory that is filled with information.  Like the title says I can open the worksheet in excel 2003 and it will run fine but if it runs in 2010 there is an error that pops up saying Run-time error "70" Permission denied.

Here is the code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim dataType As String
Dim dataName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path  'sets the directory to where the workpaper is
ChDir ".." 'Moves up a directory
ChDir (".\folder\")

direct = ThisWorkbook.Path

Worksheets("SchSB XML").Select

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(direct & "\" & flName &  ".xml", True)

a.writeline ("<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & " encoding=" _
    & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & " standalone=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "?>")
a.writeline ("<SchSB xmlns:ns1=" & Chr(34) & "http://efast.gov/2011" _
    & Chr(34) & " xmlns:xsi=" & Chr(34) & "http://ww.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" & Chr(34) & ">")
```

There is a loop after this but it contains the same a.writeline code as above that rotates through ~100 cells

Debug is showing the Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") is breaking and showing the permission denied error.

Comment: What is the value of `direct & "\" & flName` if you debug it?

Comment: Not sure if this is causing, but I don't see your dimension of `fs` If you write `Dim fs as Object` does it help? Or what if you use early binding? Does it work then?

Comment: What other variables are changing? Are both versions of Excel using the same operating systme, and the same user permissions? Based on [this post](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Permission-denied-39createObject39-800A0046-m58803.aspx) the problem may be that the Excel 2010 user is not a local admin.

Comment: Although you are using late binding, have you checked the references section in 2010 just to see if the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" is present?

Comment: Are you running both Excel 2003 and Excel 2010 on the same client?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Sorry the values are in a different sub but they are correct.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I just added that to the code with no dice.

Comment: @DanielCook  They are different machines that at least are running the same operating system but knowing the IT dept may be configured differently and I am not a local admin on either.  I do know that createobject("word.application") works and can delete/create word documents with another script in the same directories.

Comment: @MattDonnan I checked and it's present but just in another user's directory which is extremely odd.  I'm thinking that this is the issue.

Comment: @GravityKills Sounds as though that could be the issue, ideally the libraries should be stored in a directory that all user's have access to rather than a user's individual space, are you able to re-direct the reference in your current setup?

Comment: @MattDonnan I think IT just allowed access to that file so it works now even though its probably not the best solution.  If you want to provide an actual answer so I can put it as an accepted answer. Also so other people searching can more clearly see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with 'late binding' you still need to check that the entry for "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" is present in the references list, and also that it is pointing to the correct filepath, e.g a network share that user's across all computers would have access to like:

```
Z:\Lib\scrrun.dll
```

As oppose to:

```
C:\Users\"Username"\...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly because you have a row of code to the effect of: `Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` or `Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(direct & "\" & flName &  ".xml", True)` inside a loop. This may cause problems as VBA thinks you are trying to overwrite an existing file, open a file that's already open, or something to that effect. To get around this issue `CreateObject` and/ or `CreateTextFile *outside* of the loop, either before or after (most probably before), then write whatever data you want to it from inside the loop.